# How to change application language programmatically without restarting application?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, localization

I am trying application localisation in iOS .There are some static data such as button name and all which i want to localize at runtime using objectId which is present in Main.strings file under main.storyboard .But I am able to do application localisation using app restart which is wrong a bit.
Code I am using to change the application language is via userdefaults ie:

```
class func setAppleLAnguageTo(lang: String) {
    print(lang)
    let userdef = UserDefaults.standard
    UserDefaults.standard.set(["\(lang)"], forKey: "Applelanguages")

    userdef.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: Usually after that you need to reload (root) main window...  Call with .window!.rootViewController and .window?.makeKeyAndVisible() ..